# Variable number of keys to access dictionary through a function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

This function is for two keys:

```
def get(keyA, keyB)
    return mydict[keyA][keyB]
```

How can I write the following function for variable number of keys?

```
def get(*keys)
    return mydict[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[3]]...
```

Comment: And presumably you did not mean to skip `keys[2]` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate keys, and assign the item as you iterate:

```
def get(*keys):
    ret = mydict
    for key in keys:
        ret = ret[key]
    return ret
```